# How to use an Ionic generated page as app root page

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm just trying to get my feet wet with Ionic and Angular.  I have created an Ionic app with `ionic start tabs-app tabs --ts`.  I then created a page with `ionic g page event-home`.

Next, I wanted to set that generated page as my home page so, without changing anything else, I updated **app.component.ts** to

```
...
import { EventHomePage } from '../pages/event-home/event-home';
...
export Class MyApp {
    rootPage:any = EventHomePage;
}
```

Now if I try to `ionic serve`: `Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No component factory found for EventHomePage. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?`

So, I try adding it to `entryComponents` in **app.module.ts**:

```
...
import { EventHomePage } from '../pages/event-home/event-home';
...
@NgModule({
  ...
  entryComponents: [
    EventHomePage,
    ...
  ]
})
export class AppModule{}
```

Now I get `Component EventHomePage is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.`

So, trying to do what *seems* like a simple task is proving quite difficult.

How do I change the home page of an ionic generated app to a page that was generated by ionic?

Comment: The easiest way to do this will be to run `ionic g testproject blank`.  The blank project does exactly what you want with a page called "home".  Next run your `ionic g page EventHomePage` and just search for HomePage in the project and replace text.  I assume you were confused because you used the tabs initial project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you generated your page with a recent version of `ionic-cli` the page will have been created with the `@IonicPage` decorator. If so you must also have a `event-home.module.ts` file in the same folder as the `event-home.ts` file.

With that notation you don't have to import the page component in `app.component.ts` but you call the page as a string:

```
rootPage:any = 'EventHomePage';
```

See http://blog.ionicframework.com/ionic-and-lazy-loading-pt-1/ and http://blog.ionicframework.com/ionic-and-lazy-loading-pt-2/

Comment: The event-home.ts file does contain the decorator and the event-home.module.ts file was generated; however, it doesn't work with simply adding `rootPage:any = 'EventHomePage';

Comment: I just created a new project exactly like yours and generated the page the same way and it works for me. However it messes the navigation this way because you are using tabs. Do you intend to navigate to EventHomePage in a specific tab?

Answer (score 3):

You will also have to import the module in which EventHomePage is defined or you will have to add EventHomePage in the declarations of app.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

```
@NgModule({   
 declarations:[
    EventHomePage
    ],
entryComponents:[
    EventHomePage
]})
```

add in a declaration as well and it should work.